# How can I set the captions style in Word centered as default?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

When I insert a Caption in Word (in a Equation or an Illustration) their style is set as `Caption + Left` instead of `Caption` so even if I change the Caption style they appear left aligned and I have to manually change it each time. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem, and it seems to be a common one.  There's a forum discussion [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-office-word/455504-caption-alignment.html) with some Word MVPs, and the official answer seems to be that Word automatically aligns the caption with the graphic above it. (This is Word being "helpful" even though it's counter-intuitive and goes against the concept of styles.) So, if you center your graphics, your captions should show up centered.

I have tried this and confirmed that if a picture is left-aligned, selecting Insert | Caption from the right-click menu left-aligns the caption.  If the picture is centered, the caption is centered.

Comment: If you are creating U. S. Patent applications, this information is indispensable, since the USPTO wants the figure captions centered above each drawing. 

For what it's worth, all you need do is mark the object as centered, even when the width causes it to occupy all the space between the left and right margins.

Answer (score 0):

First add the caption, then go Home, click in the text of the caption and you will se that the style of text has changed to Caption text style. Right click on that style in the style window and click on Change - there you can update the caption text style to be centered and it will be centered from now on.